# Need to XPath Filter for Specific USB Key in Event Log

Tags: powershell, xpath, windows-task-scheduler, event-viewer

I am trying to make my device shutdown whenever i take out my Win 10 BitLocker USB Startup Key (TSK). I have enabled the DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational Logging to generate the appropriate logs in which I want to grab the InstanceID of the specific USB drive.

Its able to pull all the 2102 events, from all removed USBs if I do the following:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational -FilterXPath '*[System[(EventID=2102)]]'
```

However when I attempt to filter for the one specific drive, it just errors out:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational -FilterXPath '*[System[(EventID=2102)]] and *[UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[@instanceID="SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN__USB&PROD__SANDISK_3.2GEN1&REV_1.00#0401FCC4C24B5204ED6A023E9446EBDE67DADF08C86BAB77DBE89C8C17C339C#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}"]]]'
```

Whether I try changing all the `&` to `&amp;` ,or the original posted above, it comes up with the error of:

```
Get-WinEvent : No events were found that match the specified selection criteria.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Ope ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception               
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchingEventsFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[2102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NomZl.png)
Event Id 2102 General Tab (Event Viewer) -   Message

```
  Forwarded a finished Pnp or Power operation (27, 23) to the lower driver for device SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN__USB&PROD__SANDISK_3.2GEN1&REV_1.00#0401FCC4C24B5204ED6A023E9446EBDE67DADF08C86BAB77DBE89C8C17C339C#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B} with status 0x0


    Logname: Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational
    Source: DriverFrameworks-UserMode     Logged: [Date]
    Event ID: 2102                        Task Category: Pnp or Power Management to a particular device
    Level: Information                    Keywords: 
    User : LOCAL SERVICE                  Computer: [Computername]
    Op Code: (2)
```

[2102 XML View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYTX8.png)
Event Id 2102 Details Tab (Event Viewer) - XML View

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode" Guid="{2e35aaeb-857f-4beb-a418-2e6c0e54d988}" /> 
    <EventID>2102</EventID> 
    <Version>1</Version> 
    <Level>4</Level> 
    <Task>37</Task> 
    <Opcode>2</Opcode> 
    <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-09-28T22:54:17.6538118Z" /> 
    <EventRecordID>1883</EventRecordID> 
    <Correlation /> 
    <Execution ProcessID="6580" ThreadID="22636" /> 
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational</Channel> 
    <Computer>Roswell</Computer> 
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-19" /> 
   </System>
- <UserData>
 - <UMDFHostDeviceRequest xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/DriverFrameworks/UserMode/Event">
     <LifetimeId>{c09c68ed-af3b-4e1a-b2dd-17e74f17dba3}</LifetimeId> 
     <InstanceId>SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN__USB&PROD__SANDISK_3.2GEN1&REV_1.00#0401FCC4C24B5204ED6A023E9446EBDE67DADF08C86BAB77DBE89C8C17C339C#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}</InstanceId> 
     <RequestMajorCode>27</RequestMajorCode> 
     <RequestMinorCode>23</RequestMinorCode> 
     <Argument1>0x0</Argument1> 
     <Argument2>0x0</Argument2> 
     <Argument3>0x0</Argument3> 
     <Argument4>0x0</Argument4> 
     <Status>0</Status> 
    </UMDFHostDeviceRequest>
   </UserData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: And what is the error?  Have you tried filterhashtable?

Comment: Or you can try `&amp;` for `&`.

Comment: Cant copy and paste an image, that will limit the assistance you will receive as I and most here aren't willing to retype everything you already have in text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$instance = 'SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN__USB&PROD__SANDISK_3.2GEN1&REV_1.00#0401FCC4C24B5204ED6A023E9446EBDE67DADF08C86BAB77DBE89C8C17C339C#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}'

Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=2102]] and [UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[@instanceID='$instance']]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `@instanceID` to `InstanceId` and XML escaping the instance id string did the trick for me. In your case the command should be something like this:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational -FilterXPath "*[System[(EventID=2102)]] and *[UserData[UMDFHostDeviceRequest[InstanceId='SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&amp;VEN__USB&amp;PROD__SANDISK_3.2GEN1&amp;REV_1.00#0401FCC4C24B5204ED6A023E9446EBDE67DADF08C86BAB77DBE89C8C17C339C#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}']]]"
```